# Conditional adding of records to a table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have got this update script updating certain columns:

```
update oppar
set oppar_run_mode = 0,
    oppar_run_time = 0, 
    oppar_interval_ind = 'N' , 
    oppar_destination = '',
    oppar_run_date ='', 
    oppar_run_interval=''
    where ( oppar_job_name, oppar_job_rec ) 
    in 
     ( ('CSCLM' , 'XYZ')
   , ('ARCLEVEXT' , 'LMN'));
```

But there are cases where there is no record in the table **oppar** where the column 
**oppar_job_rec** is XYZ or LMN.

Now I need to **verify the existence** of `oppar_job_name=CSCLM`
then if that exists.
I need to check the existence of the Job rec coresponding to CSCLM i.e `oppar_job_rec=XYZ`
and if it does not exists I need to add a new record with these details.

```
oppar_job_name=CSCLM
oppar_job_rec=XYZ
oppar_run_mode = 0
oppar_run_time = 0 
oppar_interval_ind = 'N' 
oppar_destination = ''
oppar_run_date ='' 
oppar_run_interval=''
```

If it exists then I need to update that row.

Please help and tell me if you need more info.

But how do I perform the checking if it could be done and I need to do this on about 100 records with different values for oppar_job_rec .

`Oracle 9i Enterprise Edition release 9.2.8.0 - 64 bit Production`

Comment: What Oracle version are you using?

Comment: My Oracle version is Orcale9i Enterprise editon release 9.2.8.0 - 64 bit Production

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a SQL Merge statement: http://psoug.org/reference/merge.html

Here's some example code:

Instead of hardcoding the job_name and job_rec, build a table (if they aren't already in some table):

```
CREATE TABLE oppar_jobs (oppar_job_name VARCHAR2(200), 
                         oppar_job_rec VARCHAR2(200));

INSERT INTO oppar_jobs (oppar_job_name,oppar_job_rec) 
                VALUES ('CSCLM','XYZ');

INSERT INTO oppar_jobs (oppar_job_name,oppar_job_rec) 
                VALUES ('ARCLEVEXT','LMN');
```

Then you can run a MERGE as follows:

```
MERGE
    INTO  oppar 
    USING oppar_jobs 
    ON  ( oppar_jobs.oppar_job_name = oppar.oppar_job_name 
     AND  oppar_jobs.oppar_job_rec = oppar.oppar_job_rec)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
    UPDATE
    SET oppar_run_mode = 0,
        oppar_run_time = 0, 
        oppar_interval_ind = 'N' , 
        oppar_destination = '',
        oppar_run_date ='', 
        oppar_run_interval=''
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN
    INSERT ( oppar_job_name,
             oppar_job_rec,
             oppar_run_mode,
             oppar_run_time,
             oppar_interval_ind,
             oppar_destination,
             oppar_run_date,
             oppar_run_interval)
    VALUES ( oppar_jobs.oppar_job_name,
             oppar_jobs.oppar_job_rec,
             0,
             0,
             'N',
             '',
             '',
             '');
```

Comment: It is more efficient to make just one pass through the table, so a MERGE statement is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using `9i` `merge` is not an option; So, you have a number of options, 2 that involve PL?SQL.

*Option 1: update then insert*

If you don't care about errors occurring you can just run your update then run your insert. The update may do nothing and the insert may cause a primary key violation but at least you know everything has been done. If you do this each insert would have to be done separately.

*Option 2: update then insert with error catching*

Using PL/SQL you could do something like the following,

```
update my_table
   set <col1> = :col1
 where <blah>

if SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 then
   insert into my_table
   values < my values >
elsif SQL%ROWCOUNT =  1 then
   insert less...
end if;
```

*Option 3: insert then update with error catching*

```
insert into my_table
values < my values >

exception when dup_val_on_index then
   update my_table
      set <col1> : :col1
    where <blah>
```